# Creating a Flowchart with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, flowchart

I'm trying to create a structure using HTML / CSS that can accommodate multiple nodes.
In the future I intend to integrate this with an Angular application, but at the moment I only wish to create this structure.
My desire is to create a structure that can receive multiple sequence nodes, and at times ramifications.

[image: Prototype]

I tried to create a structure using :: after and :: before of CSS3. But I think I ended up getting pretty confused in the implementation. Follow the code below.

```css
.node:first-child::before {
  border: 0 none;
}

.node::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-right: 4px solid #067a2d;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
}

.node:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.node span {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 2px solid #673ab7;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.nodeBranch {
  column-count: 2;
}

.nodeBranch::before,
.nodeBranch::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  border-top: 4px solid #067a2d;
}

.branch {
  padding: 0px;
}

.branch .node:first-child::before,
.branch .node:last-child::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-right: 4px solid #067a2d;
  width: 50%;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <div class="node">
    <span>Step 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="node">
    <span>Step 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="node">
    <span>Step 3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="nodeBranch">
    <div class="branch">
      <div class="node">
        <span>Step 4.1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="branch">
      <div class="node">
        <span>Step 4.2</span>
      </div>
      <div class="nodeBranch">
        <div class="branch">
          <div class="node">
            <span>Step 5.1</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="branch">
          <div class="node">
            <span>Step 5.2</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="node">
    <span>Step 7</span>
  </div>
  <div class="node">
    <span>Step 8</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for all the possible help.

Comment: Instead of using plain html/css to achieve this I would recommend to use [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API).

Comment: I want to insert angular components dynamically within the nodes.
So I guess it would not be possible using Canvas. But I will try. Thank you.

Comment: First and foremost you need to add '.node,.nodeBranch,.Branch { position: relative }' to your code. 'absolute' child elements need to be positioned 'relative' to their parent. Now you will see that you are close to a solution after all. The logical structure of your HTML code appears OK.

Comment: Let me know if you are still looking for a solution (it has been a while now). I started from scratch to get a working example (added some fun goodies too). It just no longer resembles your code, at all...